# 404 not found Laravel with route argument

Tags: php, laravel

I come to you today because I don't really understand where my problem is coming from. When I try to pass a dynamic argument in my url, I systematically fall on a 404 page. I looked in my db, there is the article, I looked in my model, it points well to this table of the db, I looked at my controller, I specify this article well... I do not understand too much.

My web.php:

```
Route::get('/article/{article}', 'ArticleController@index');
```

My controller:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index($article)
    {
        $scopedArticle = Article::where('id', $article)->firstOrFail();
        return view('article', compact('scopedArticle'));
    }
}
```

My model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articles';

    protected $fillable = [
        'titre', 'image', 'description',
    ];
}
```

My database:

[image: Database]

So I don't really understand...

Comment: what dynamic argument are you trying to pass into your url? also, what error are you getting?

Comment: Btw, You can use `Article::findOrFail($article);` instead of `Article::where('id', $article)->firstOrFail();` if `$article` doesn't match with the `id` then it will raise a 404 error. You can dd the $article  and debug.

Comment: @sta I've already tried to debug by doing multiple things: Trying to output all articles with a ::all(), changing the name of the variable doesn't help.... When I try to make a dd of an article, I still have a 404. I deduce that it doesn't fit in my public function.
No errors occur, except for a 404

Comment: Give the output of `dd($article);` is it `1`?

Comment: @sta I can't make a dd. I've a 404 error before my public function, so I can't pass any code

Comment: Do you have any route group? would you please send your web.php completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding) there is no need to add `$scopedArticle = Article::where('id', $article)->firstOrFail();`

Example usage:

goto http://yourstie.com/article/1

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Article $article)
    {
        return view('article', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I just updated my code but I still get the same result. A 404 without being able to make dd

Comment: Yes and without reasons, with repeating f5, I've finally my page in front of my eyes... Incredible

Comment: No problem, on another note it is good practice to use `show()` instead of `index()`, `index()` would be reserved for viewing all articles and `show()` is used to show a single article